# How to remotely connect to MySQL database which is in Private EC2 instance to Visual Studio in localhost

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have created 2 EC2 instance one is public which has public IP and private IP and other one is private instance which has only private IP. Only public instance can access private instance and private instance contains MYSQL database. Public instance contain webserver which I publish from local pc. I want to know how to access to database which is in my private instance to my ASP.net project so I can establish SQL connection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The common way to access a private instance, rds or any other resource in a VPC from your local workstation is through **ssh tunnel**.

So basically, you would establish ssh tunnel to a **public instance**, which would then forward connections to the private instance with mysql. Having the tunnel, you would access your database using `localhost` on your local workstation.

There is a number of tutorials on how to do it. Examples are:

- [Connecting to an AWS RDS database through an SSH tunnel](https://help.data.world/hc/en-us/articles/360042882294-Connecting-to-an-AWS-RDS-database-through-an-SSH-tunnel)
- [Accessing a private RDS instance via an ssh tunnel](https://griggheo.medium.com/accessing-a-private-rds-instance-via-an-ssh-tunnel-4be098b128ef)
- [SSH Tunnels (How to Access AWS RDS Locally Without Exposing it to Internet)](https://serebrov.github.io/html/2018-01-11-aws-ec2-ssh-tunnel.html)

Comment: No I'm not using AWS RDS. I have install MYSQL server in private instance

Comment: @VishwajeetGade It does not matter if its not RDS, or ElasticSearch or whatever. A procedure of using ssh tunnel is same. You can use ssh tunnel to access any resource in a private subnet of a vpc through a public bastion host.

Comment: @VishwajeetGade How did it go? Did you manage to connect?

Comment: Thank you for you help @Marcin . yes I did manage to connect using SSH tunnel but not exactly how you said. I have deploy my project in public EC2 instance and make some changes in code. Once again thank you for your help and sorry for late reply. I was busy in that assignment

Comment: @VishwajeetGade No problem. Glad it worked out:-)

Answer (score 1):

You could run a port redirector software on the publicly accessible instance, to redirect traffic to the private instance, then open up the public instance's firewall to accept traffic from your IP only, to the port redirector port

Or, use something like ngrok on the private instance to funnel traffic through their proxies and make it like MySQL is running on your machine

Or install MySQL studio software on the public instance and access it via RDP

But for all the messing around it is, I'd just give the private instance a public ip address, lock it down to being accessible to your IP only and use it directly